# Get number of opened application windows in linux

Tags: linux, bash, x11

I want to detect how many instances of a specific application, managed by the window manager, are opened. At the moment, I have this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# wmctrl required

pids=$(pidof $1)
IFS=' ' read -a pid_arr <<< "$pids"
matches=0
for pid in "${pid_arr[@]}"
do
    matching_lines=$(wmctrl -l -p | egrep -c "^.+\b.+\b$pid\b")
    matches=$((matches + $matching_lines))
done
echo $matches
```

Say I have firefox open three times and I pass `firefox` as an argument, the function will only return the right number if there were no "sub-windows" (e.g. preference windows) opened. Otherwise, the function will count these windows too.

I want to get the number of windows without the "sub-windows".

P.S.: Made some changes. To count the number of windows without their dialog-windows, this is my current solution:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

pids=$(pidof $1)
IFS=' ' read -r -a pid_arr <<< "$pids"
matches=0
for pid in "${pid_arr[@]}"
do
    ids=$(wmctrl -l -p | awk '$3=='$pid'{printf $1" "}')
    IFS=' ' read -r -a id_arr <<< "$ids"
    for id in "${id_arr[@]}"
    do
        if ! xprop -id "$id" |
            egrep -q '(WM_TRANSIENT_FOR|_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG)'
        then
            ((matches++))
        fi
    done
done
echo $matches
```

But in the case of firefox, the script cannot distinguish between the browser window and its preference window because none of them is a dialog window.

The above script is sufficient for me, because I use it to figure out how many windows (without dialog windows) of xfce4-appfinder are open. For xfce4-appfinder the script works, because its preference window can easily be recognized as a dialog window. In firefox the preference window can even be opened standalone by calling `firefox -preferences`. To recognize windows like this as some kind of "sub-window" is maybe impossible.

Here are my results of `xprop` and `xwininfo` for both the browser and preference window of firefox:

`xwininfo` (browser):

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x1c0007f "bash - Get number of opened application windows in linux - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox"

  Root window id: 0xa1 (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x1400048 (has no name)
     1 child:
     0x1c00080 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +1+37

  Absolute upper-left X:  2
  Absolute upper-left Y:  38
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  14
  Width: 956
  Height: 511
  Depth: 24
  Visual: 0x20
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x22 (installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: no
  Corners:  +2+38  -962+38  -962-531  +2-531
  -geometry 956x511+0+22

  Bit gravity: NorthWestGravity
  Window gravity: NorthWestGravity
  Backing-store hint: NotUseful
  Backing-planes to be preserved: 0xffffffff
  Backing pixel: 0
  Save-unders: No

  Someone wants these events:
      KeyPress
      KeyRelease
      ButtonPress
      ButtonRelease
      EnterWindow
      LeaveWindow
      PointerMotion
      Exposure
      VisibilityChange
      StructureNotify
      FocusChange
      PropertyChange
  Do not propagate these events:
  Override redirection?: No

  Window manager hints:
      Client accepts input or input focus: Yes
      Initial state is Normal State
      Displayed on desktop 0
      Window type:
          Normal
      Process id: 792 on host T530

  Normal window size hints:
      Program supplied minimum size: 300 by 71
      Program supplied maximum size: 32767 by 32767
      Program supplied window gravity: NorthWestGravity
  No zoom window size hints defined

  No window shape defined
  No border shape defined
```

`xwininfo` (preferences):

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x1c046ef "Firefox Preferences"

  Root window id: 0xa1 (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x1400060 (has no name)
     1 child:
     0x1c046f0 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +961+37

  Absolute upper-left X:  962
  Absolute upper-left Y:  38
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  14
  Width: 956
  Height: 1040
  Depth: 24
  Visual: 0x20
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x22 (installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no0x1c00001
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: no
  Corners:  +962+38  -2+38  -2-2  +962-2
  -geometry 956x1040-0-0

  Bit gravity: NorthWestGravity
  Window gravity: NorthWestGravity
  Backing-store hint: NotUseful
  Backing-planes to be preserved: 0xffffffff
  Backing pixel: 0
  Save-unders: No

  Someone wants these events:
      KeyPress
      KeyRelease
      ButtonPress
      ButtonRelease
      EnterWindow
      LeaveWindow
      PointerMotion
      Exposure
      VisibilityChange
      StructureNotify
      FocusChange
      PropertyChange
  Do not propagate these events:
  Override redirection?: No

  Window manager hints:
      Client accepts input or input focus: Yes
      Initial state is Normal State
      Displayed on desktop 0
      Window type:
          Normal
      Process id: 792 on host T530

  Normal window size hints:
      Program supplied location: 0, 0
      Program supplied minimum size: 604 by 594
      Program supplied maximum size: 32767 by 32767
      Program supplied window gravity: NorthWestGravity
  No zoom window size hints defined

  No window shape defined
  No border shape defined
```

`xprop` (browser):

```
_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
        Client accepts input or input focus: True
        Initial state is Normal State.
        bitmap id # to use for icon: 0x1c00082
        bitmap id # of mask for icon: 0x1c00083
        window id # of group leader: 0x1c00001
_NET_STARTUP_ID(UTF8_STRING) = "xfce4-appfinder/|usr|lib|firefox|firefox/756-0-T530_TIME21351"
WM_WINDOW_ROLE(STRING) = "browser"
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO(_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO) = 0x6c, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 29360257
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 1758669
_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x1c00080
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x1c00001
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 792
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "T530"
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified minimum size: 300 by 71
        program specified maximum size: 32767 by 32767
        window gravity: NorthWest
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "bash - Get number of opened application windows in linux - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox"
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "bash - Get number of opened application windows in linux - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "bash - Get number of opened application windows in linux - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "bash - Get number of opened application windows in linux - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox"
```

`xprop` (preferences)

```
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
        Client accepts input or input focus: True
        Initial state is Normal State.
        bitmap id # to use for icon: 0x1c046f2
        bitmap id # of mask for icon: 0x1c046f3
        window id # of group leader: 0x1c00001
WM_WINDOW_ROLE(STRING) = "Preferences"
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO(_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO) = 0x6c, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 29378289
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 1456410
_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x1c046f0
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x1c00001
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 792
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "T530"
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified location: 0, 0
        program specified minimum size: 604 by 594
        program specified maximum size: 32767 by 32767
        window gravity: NorthWest
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Browser", "Firefox"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "Firefox Preferences"
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Firefox Preferences"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Firefox Preferences"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Firefox Preferences"
```

Comment: Something like this might work `xwininfo  -tree -root | grep "Mozilla Firefox" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 xwininfo -all -id  | grep "Process id" | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: What's an application? What's an instance of an application? Can you give rigorous definitions? A window manager manages windows. My window manager knows nothing about any entity called application. You can enumerate windows and get information about them.

Comment: @n.m.: Maybe I should use the names "normal windows" and "dialog windows", although I have no rigorous definitions either. But `xprop` can sometimes distinguish "dialog" and "normal" windows: if `WM_TRANSIENT_FOR(WINDOW)` is set and/or `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG` -> it's a dialog window. But in the case of firefox, its preference window is not recognizable as a dialog window.

Comment: Can you post the `xwininfo` and `xprop` output from the firefox windows that you are having trouble distinguishing? Maybe there's something in there we can use to tell them apart.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there's a simple answer to this. You are probably going to need to inspect the windows more closely and weed-out any that aren't what you want.

The group leader property on a window might be useful. (Some sub-windows should have this and main windows may not).

You can also look at the full WM_CLASS and WM_WINDOW_ROLE values which might help you distinguish between window types.

The _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE, etc. properties are also likely to be helpful in figuring out what "kind" of window you are looking at.

Play around with `xwininfo` and `xprop` on the various windows on your display and you'll see what you can find.

Answer (score 1):

The follow give you a list of running application which have a windows:

(Tested on Debian 10)

```
# copy to terminal and press enter, for getting list of all programs with window
wmctrl -l

# Or grep if you look only for count of only one application
wmctrl -l -p | grep name_of_application
```

For getting the count of running programms, count the lines or the programm IDs of the output.